# Play video with subtitles - Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, html5-video

Currently I have a working app which streams movies using torrents. I would like to add subtitles functionality to this app. Currently I'm streaming the movies to a HTML5 video tag. Are there any media players components which supports subtitles searching? If not, what's the best approach to implement such a thing?